# Help with understanding the phrase "to the effect" in this context

Tags: meaning

What does *to the effect* mean in this sentence?

> Consider suppositions to the effect that someone is supposing something.

Comment: Please show the results of your previous research.

Comment: Where did you read this sentence? Can you provide greater context, please? Have you looked in a dictionary, and what did you understand?

Comment: Based on the dictionary definition, and my understanding, of the phrase (http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/to-the-effect-that), your example sentence doesn't make a lot of sense to me. Can you expand your question, or provide another example sentence?

Answer (score 1):

'[To the effect](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/to%20that%20effect)' is usually used to express that what is being communicated is short, general form of what was communicated in it's original form.

It doesn't make an enormous amount of sense in the sentence you've included because the nature of that sentence seems somewhat circular.